# Spring MVC @PathVariable with a underscore (_) and dot (.) gets truncated

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/abc/{something}")
```

now my **something** is a type of String comes == ABC.HELLO_WORLD_COOL.AMAZING_GREAT

how can I achieve this thing into my **@PathVariable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will allow dot(.) and underscore(_).

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/abc/{something:.+}")
```